# TypeScript var scope versus JavaScript var scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, var, let

Ran across some interesting differences between docs on this very common question.

According to the TS docs, variables declared with `var`will leak out of the containing function, but on MSDN it states the `var` data will not leak and instead is accessible throughout the containing function. This may be just a difference in how Typescript handles var compared to how ECMAScript does, looking to SO for feedback on this.

[According to the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html)

> Block-scoping When a variable is declared using let, it uses what some
>   call lexical-scoping or block-scoping. **Unlike variables declared with**
>   **var whose scopes leak out to their containing function**, block-scoped
>   variables are not visible outside of their nearest containing block or
>   for-loop.

[But according to the MSDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> Variables declared by let have their scope in the block for which they
>   are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks. In this way, let
>   works very much like var. **The main difference is that the scope of a**
>   **var variable is the entire enclosing function**:

Answer (score 4):

These are two different ways of saying the same thing

The doc says (emphasis mine):

> variables declared with var whose scopes leak out **to** their containing function

which is *different* from saying

> variables declared with var whose scopes leak out **of** their containing function

Comment: your're totally right, missed that small detail. will accept this when I am able too!

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is **transcompiled** to JavaScript. When you look at the JavaScript output generated from your TypeScript code, you will see that a variable declared using the keyword `var` is simply declared the same way.

So the scope is the also same: the variable is accessible in the entire containing function. This is sometimes referred to as [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: Hoisting is a related but different concept.